# How to check whether notifications are enabled or not for my app command line on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, notifications, big-sur

How to check whether notifications are enabled or not for my app from terminal / command line on macOS Big Sur?

Also, I want to forcefully enable or disable notifications using administrative/root privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after spending whole day and reading 100s of articles/post I got my answer. Just replace `<your app bundle id>` with bundle id for which you want to perform the check.

```
#!/bin/bash

# check whether notifiactions are enabled for logged in user or not
# if not enabled, enable it for your app

# Get the current logged in user
user=$(echo "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | scutil | awk '/Name :/ { print $3 }')

#Location of the notification center preferences plist for the current user
notification_plist="/Users/$user/Library/Preferences/com.apple.ncprefs.plist"

#Count of the bundles existing in the plist
count=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :apps" "${notification_plist}" | grep -c "bundle-id")

#Flag to indicate if the notification center should be restarted
restart=0

for ((index=1; index<"${count}"; index++)); do
  bundle_id=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print apps:${index}:bundle-id" "${notification_plist}");
      if [[ "${bundle_id}" == <your app bundle id> ]]; then
         flags_value=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print apps:${index}:flags" "${notification_plist}");
         if [[ $flags_value == 276* ]]; then
            /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :apps:${index}:flags 41951246" "${notification_plist}"
            restart=1
         fi
      fi
done

if [[ ${restart} = 1 ]]; then
    # Restart notification center to make changes take effect.
    killall sighup usernoted
    sleep 1
    # wait for notification center to start again
    while ! pgrep -x "usernoted" >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done
fi
```

Above code worked for me. Others may need to tweak *flags_value* as per their requirement.